# I want no idention after \newpage

Tags: formatting

I defined with `\parindent=0cm` that there should be no idention after new paragraphs. But the very first `\chapter` and every `\newpage` is idented! I don't want to have that, so how can I work around?
Example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\selectlanguage{english}



\parindent=0cm

\geometry{a4paper,left=20mm,right=20mm, top=1cm, bottom=1cm, includeheadfoot}


\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[L]{\small{\textbf{Spacecraft Dynamics\\
Problem sheet 1}}}
\fancyhead[R]{\small{2012-09-10}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}


\begin{document}

\chapter{\textbf{\begin{large}
Problem P1: Rotations in $\mathbb{R}^2$
\end{large}}}\\
text text text
\newpage
\chapter{\textbf{\begin{large}
Problem P1: Rotations in $\mathbb{R}^2$
\end{large}}}\\
text text text\\
\chapter{\textbf{\begin{large}
Problem P1: Rotations in $\mathbb{R}^2$
\end{large}}}\\
\end{document}
```

Comment: create an example. With `\parindent=0cm` in the preamble there will be no indenting.

Comment: Ok here is an example:

Comment: Remove the \begin{large} from inside the chapter title and remove the spurious `\\ `

Answer (score 3):

You are using `article` which does not define `\chapter` (one of your packages has defined it to be `\relax` so it does nothing rather than generate an error as it would normally.

If you use report things work better:

```
  \documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\selectlanguage{english}



\parindent=0cm

\geometry{a4paper,left=20mm,right=20mm, top=1cm, bottom=1cm, includeheadfoot}


\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[L]{\small{\textbf{Spacecraft Dynamics\\
Problem sheet 1}}}
\fancyhead[R]{\small{2012-09-10}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Problem P1: Rotations in $\mathbb{R}^2$}
text text text
\newpage
\chapter{Problem P1: Rotations in $\mathbb{R}^2$}
text text text
\chapter{Problem P1: Rotations in $\mathbb{R}^2$}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

your `\chapter` are senseless with documentclass `article`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\parindent=0cm
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\geometry{a4paper,left=20mm,right=20mm, top=1cm, bottom=1cm, includeheadfoot}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[L]{\small\textbf{Spacecraft Dynamics\\Problem sheet 1}}
\fancyhead[R]{\small2012-09-10}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\begin{document}

{\bfseries\large Problem P1: Rotations in $\mathbb{R}^2$}

text text text

\newpage
{\bfseries\large Problem P1: Rotations in $\mathbb{R}^2$}

text text text

{\bfseries\large Problem P1: Rotations in $\mathbb{R}^2$}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The way to say 'thank you' on StackExchange is by 'upvoting' good answers and by 'accepting' the one answer that provides a complete (or the best) solution to the problem given.  :-)